# Solving $a^5 \equiv 15 \pmod{385}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Is there a general way of approaching problems like $a^5 \equiv 15 \pmod{385}$? I know the first step is to break up the modulus into its prime factors ($5, 7,$ and $11$, in this case). How do I deal with the exponent though? It's been a while since I looked at number theory, but I remember the whole question of singular and nonsingular roots comes up.

Comment: Now solve $a^5 \equiv 15$ modulo each of the three factors.  Then combine the results using the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: As Ross suggests, make a little table of $0^5, 1^5, 2^5, 3^5, 4^5 \pmod 5.$ It is not hard, any time you go over $5$ you just reduce. Same for $0^5, 1^5, 2^5, 3^5, 4^5, 5^5, 6^5 \pmod 7.$ If you prefer, $1^5, 2^5, 3^5,(-3)^5, (-2)^5, (-1)^5 \pmod 7.$ Similar for 11. You don't need a calculator and you don't need formulas

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you, so much!

Comment: $a^5\equiv 15\pmod{11}\implies a^5\equiv 4\pmod{11} \implies a^{10}\equiv 16\pmod{11}$ which is false by Fermat's little theorem, so there are no solutions.

Comment: I was wondering about that!  I only saw the title on the main page, and was working on this for a couple of minutes (I'm really no good at number theory) and wondering how there could be any solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Taking into account that $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ is a field if $p$ is prime, it is equivalent to solving
\begin{cases}
a^5\equiv 0\mod 5\iff a\equiv 0\mod 5, \\
a^5\equiv 1\mod 7\iff a^6\equiv 1\equiv a \mod 7 &\text{ by Fermat},\\
a^5\equiv 4\mod 11.
\end{cases}
However, Fermat asserts that if $a\not\equiv 0\mod 11$, we have $a^{10}=(a^5)^2\equiv 1$, whence $a^5\equiv \pm 1\mod 11$. Therefore there's no solution modulo $11$, and consequently, no solution modulo $385$.

Answer (score 0):

The "general way" is to use indices.  For each prime power, find a primitive root $r$ and generate the table of indices.  Then you can solve

$$x^k \equiv a \pmod{p}$$

by taking "logs" of both sides.  For instance, take $p=7$.  The smallest primitive root of $7$ is $3$, so compute mod $7$:

$3^0 =1$, $3^1=3$, $3^2=2$, $3^3=6$, $3^4=4$, $3^5=5$.

So your indices are

$\mbox{ind}_3 1=0$, $\mbox{ind}_3 3=1$, $\mbox{ind}_3 2=2$,$\mbox{ind}_3 6=3$,$\mbox{ind}_3 4=4$,$\mbox{ind}_3 5=5$.

Now if you want to solve $x^5\equiv 3 \pmod{7}$ you can take indices of both sides:

$$\mbox{ind}_3 x^5 \equiv \mbox{ind}_3 3 \pmod{6}$$

$$5\mbox{ind}_3 x \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$$

$$\mbox{ind}_3 x \equiv 5 \pmod{6}$$

$$x \equiv 5 \pmod{7}.$$